# Can't Persist Radio Button value in LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button, local-storage

I'm writing a code to store the information of the user in local storage.
The problem is that only the radio buttons are not working.

I have tested changing the order of the calling functions but nothing works:

```
function fGnere() {
var rdo = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked')
localStorage.setItem('genre', rdo.value)
}
```

I expect the radio button's value to be stored inside the localstorage :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  So what's the error message that you're receiving?

Comment: Wat does rdo.value output? can you console.log it

Comment: there is no error message , the thing is that the value does not exist in the localstore at all

Comment: it outputs either "homme" or "femme" / I'm writing in french so it will be either man or woman

Comment: the radio has a .checked, not really a .value as far as the client is concerned. if not explicitly set via attrib, it should be null, which is why it doesn't show up in localStorage.

Comment: The pseudo selector :checked will only get the checked radio buttons, why dont just use other selector?

Comment: `radio buttons`, well `querySelector` only returns 1 radio item.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a page we can look at? It might be that it's in an iframe and

```
var rdo = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked')
```

is returning null.

Answer (score 0):

```
function fGnere() {
    var rdo = document.querySelector('input[name="genre"]').value
    localStorage.setItem('genre', rdo)
}
```

Use name to get the element and it's value and then store the same in localStorage

I used name as 'genre' here, I am guessing you'll have multiple radio button with same name for forming a group, so you can use the name instead